# Singular Procedure: Vanishing polynomial function (A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra)

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, finite-fields, computer-algebra-systems, singular-cas

I have recently started studying the computer algebra system Singular with help of [the book](https://nms.kcl.ac.uk/andreas.recknagel/paul/Greuel,%20Pfister%20--%20A%20Singular%20Introduction%20to%20Commutative%20Algebra.pdf) „A Singular Introduction to Commutative Algebra“ by Gert-Martin Greuel & Gerhard Pfister.

Since a few days now I‘m stuck on Exercise 1.1.13.
„Write a SINGULAR procedure, depending on two integers $p,d$, with $p$ prime, which returns all polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ of degree $d$ such that the corresponding polynomial function vanishes. Use the procedure to display all $f \in (\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z})[X]$ of degree $\leq$ 6 such that $\tilde{f}=0$“ (Annotation: $\tilde{f}$ is the polynomial function).

If I had to write that function in Python/ C++, I would recursively define all polynomials of degree $d-p$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ and then multiply all of them with $X^p-X$. Unfortunately that algorithm did not work in Singular as expected. Since this is one of the first exercises of the book I think that there has to be any clue working with Singular functionalities to solve that exercise in a more convenient way. Working through the libraries and Singular functionalities in the book I can‘t find any suitable procedure or functionality that would be helpfull in this case. Either my algorithm is wrong or Singular is requiring a different solution.

Now I‘m requesting help from someone with Singular experience or anyone that studied the book mentioned above.

Comment: Your idea seems promising, though it could of course be refined.  When you say "that algorithm did not work in Singular as expected," what exactly was wrong?  A more brute force algorithm would be (1) Generate all polynomials of degree $d$ and (2) Test whether each of these "vanishes".

Comment: I'm not familiar with Singular, but a polynomial vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if it is divisible by $X^p-X$. So describing polynomials of degree $d$ as sequences of coefficients $c=(c_0,\ldots,c_d)\in\Bbb{F}_p^d$, the polynomials that vanish correspond to the sequences for which every subsequence of step size $p-1$ sums to $0$ and $c_0=0$. To generate them all, simply generate all sequences of length $d-(p-1)$ starting with $0$, and then choose the last $p-1$ coefficients (uniquely) to meet the requirements.

Comment: @hardmath I finally wrote a working solution and uploaded it. The brute force method had immense computation time (if recursively implemented). This is why I chose the multiplication method.

Comment: @Servaes I got the idea, that the subsequences of step size $p-1$ sum to $0$. But I don't get the $d-(p-1)$-part and what comes after. Could you explain in detail? Maybe with use of an example?

Comment: @lambda My previous comment was off by $1$; there are $d+1$ coefficients, so generate all sequence of length $(d+1)-(p-1)$ starting with $0$, and then choose the last $p-1$ coefficients (uniquely) to meet the requirements.

Comment: For example, for $p=5$ and $d=13$ just take an arbitrary sequence of length $10$ in $\Bbb{F}_5$ starting with $0$, for example
$$(0,1,3,2,4,3,0,4,2,3).$$
Now complete the list with $4$ more entries so that all $p-1$-step subsequences sum to $0$. This yields
$$(0,1,3,2,4,3,0,4,2,3,2,4,4,3),$$
corresponding to the polynomial
$$3X^{13}+4X^{12}+4X^{11}+2X^{10}+3X^9+2X^8+4X^7+0X^6+3X^5+4X^4+2X^3+3X^2+1X+0.$$

Comment: One way to think about @Servaes approach is by *interpolation*.  That is, having chosen the highest degree coefficients, the last $p$ coefficients should interpolate the additive inverses of those highest degree terms evaluated at $x=0,1,\ldots,p-1$.

Comment: @Servaes thanks for your explanations! I made myself some examples too and I think I got it now! Brilliant idea, even if I think I can‘t implement this one in Singular. One could implement this in Python for instance. Nevertheless I really like this way of thinking!

Comment: @hardmath thanks for bringing the „inverse“ idea up. That really helped me to understand the underlying concept of this approach!

Comment: @hardmath The way I thought about it, is simply starting from an arbitrary polynomial, and then subtracting its remainder after division by $X^p-X$. The result vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$, and after considering which initial polynomials yield the same output, it turns out that it suffices to start from polynomials that end with $p$ zeros. I have consolidated my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else, beware that the desired procedure itself demands exorbitant amounts of runtime: For given values $p$ and $d$, if $d\geq p $ the output consists of $p^{d-p+1}$ polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_p$, requiring a total of
$$(d+1)p^{d-p+1},$$
elements of $\Bbb{F}_p$ to represent. As the size of the desired output is exponential in $d$, certainly the runtime will at least exponential.

---

As for an effective algorithm; as you note a polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}_p$ vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if it is divisible by $X^p-X$. Polynomial long division shows that mod $X^p-X$ we have $X^i\equiv X^{i+(p-1)}$ for all $i\geq 1$, and so for an arbitrary polynomial $f=\sum_{i=0}^d c_iX^i\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$
we have
$$f\equiv c_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\left(\sum_{j\geq0}c_{i+(p-1)j}\right)X^i\pmod{X^p-X}.$$
This shows that $f$ vanishes if and only if $c_0=0$ and $\sum_{j\geq0}c_{i+(p-1)j}=0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$.

In particular, if $d\leq p-1$ then this shows that $f\equiv0$, so there are no such polynomials for $d<p$, except perhaps $d=0$ if you consider the zero polynomial to have degree $0$. If $d\geq p$ then the constraints on the coefficients are equivalent to
$$c_0=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad c_i=-\sum_{j\geq1}c_{i+(p-1)j}\quad\text{ for all }\quad i\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}.$$
In other words, the first $p$ coefficients of $f$ are uniquely determined by the remaining coefficients of $f$, and there are no constraints on the remaining coefficients of $f$. So every choice of coefficients $c_p,c_{p+1},\ldots,c_d\in\Bbb{F}_p$ (with $c_d\neq0$) yields a unique polynomail of degree $d$ that vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$. This yields the following algorithm:

1. For $c_p,c_{p+1},\ldots,c_{d-1}$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$ and $c_d\in\Bbb{F}_p^{\times}$:
2. $\qquad$For $i$ in $\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$
3. $\qquad\qquad$Set $c_i:=-\sum_{j\geq1}c_{i+(p-1)j}$.
4. $\qquad$Print $f:=\sum_{i=1}^dc_iX^i$.

This requires $d+2-2p$ additions per polynomial, so the runtime is a linear in the output.

---

Another way to reach the same construction is as follows:

1. Take an arbitrary polynomial $f\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ of degree $d$.
2. Compute the unique $g\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ with $\deg g<p$ such that $g\equiv f\pmod{X^p-X}$.
3. Output $f-g$.

The computation in step $2$ is a matter of polynomial long division. Then
$$f=(X^p-X)h+g,$$
which shows that $f-g$ vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$. Of course every polynomial of degree $d$ that vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$ arises in this way, because if $f\in\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ vanishes on $\Bbb{F}_p$ then $g\equiv0$.

Comment: Isn't the output consisting of $(p-1)p^{d-p}$ elements since the leading coefficient of degree $d$ is not supposed to vanish? Thanks for your answer, I will study that carefully

Comment: @lambda There are $p^{d-p+1}$ polynomials, and each polynomial has $d+1$ coefficients, hence $(d+1)p^{d-p+1}$ elements in total. There are indeed some restrictions; the constant coefficients are all $0$, and the leading coefficients are all nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally did it after uncountable tedious hours! The coding is not very elegant but Singular is a little bit sensitive as far as for-loops, recursion and deceleration is concerned. Due to the recursion this implementation will not work for larger $d-p$

```
ring A = 5, x, dp;
LIB "general.lib";

proc allpoly(int p, int d, int #) // p prime, d degree
{
    list L;
    int j;
    int k;
    if(d!=0)
    {
        list A = allpoly(p,d-1,0);
        for(int i=1; i<=size(A);i++)
        {
            if(# == 0)
            {
                for(k=0; k<p; k++)
                {
                    L = insert(L,k*x^d + A[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(j=1; j<p; j++)
                {
                    L = insert(L,j*x^d + A[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        for(int t=0;t<p;t++)
        {
            L = insert(L,t);
        }
    }
    return(L);
}

attrib(allpoly,"default_arg",1);

proc multi(poly f) // multiplying a polynomial with x^p - x where p is the characteristic of ring A
{
    return(f * (x^(ringlist(A)[1]) - x));
}

proc vanish(int p, int d) // p prime, d degree, d => p
{
    if(p>d)
    {
        list L = (0);
        return(L);
    }
    else
    {
        list A = allpoly(p,d-p);
        list L = apply(A, multi);
        if(p==d) // will sort out the 0 polynomial if p = d
        {
            L = delete(L,size(L));
        }
        return(L);
    }
}
```

If we now apply  for instance `vanish(5,6)` we get the output:

```
[1]:
   -x6+x2
[2]:
   -2x6+2x2
[3]:
   2x6-2x2
[4]:
   x6-x2
[5]:
   -x6+x5+x2-x
[6]:
   -2x6+x5+2x2-x
[7]:
   2x6+x5-2x2-x
[8]:
   x6+x5-x2-x
[9]:
   -x6+2x5+x2-2x
[10]:
   -2x6+2x5+2x2-2x
[11]:
   2x6+2x5-2x2-2x
[12]:
   x6+2x5-x2-2x
[13]:
   -x6-2x5+x2+2x
[14]:
   -2x6-2x5+2x2+2x
[15]:
   2x6-2x5-2x2+2x
[16]:
   x6-2x5-x2+2x
[17]:
   -x6-x5+x2+x
[18]:
   -2x6-x5+2x2+x
[19]:
   2x6-x5-2x2+x
[20]:
   x6-x5-x2+x
```

which should be correct.

If someone has a better solution that maybe does use some exclusive Singular functionalities which I'm not aware of I would be glad if you could share it with me.

Comment: Minor nitpick; the exercise asks for all polynomials of degree $d$ that vanish on $\Bbb{F}_p$, but your code returns all polynomials of degree *at most* $d$ that vanish on $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @Servaes I corrected that :)